# Why do I get CORS errors even though I'm allowing all origins?

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

So I 've made a web app using Vue, and I'm using ASP.NET Web App (.NET 5) for the backend.
When I run the Web API locally on `localhost:44393` it works just great making POST & GET requests from the client that's running locally.
I then go to click "Publish" to send the files over to where I'm hosting.

At this point I change the URL that the client uses to make requests to https://api.mywebsite.com which is the same website as the one that was running locally since I published it now.
(it makes these requests using fetch so it would be `fetch("https://api.mywebsite.com/TheController/AddServer"` for instance)

This is where it gets weird because when I make a post request to register or sign in, it works just fine, but as soon as I go to "Add post" which is a form that posts to a different endpoint on the API, I get this error.

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/TheController/AddPost'
> from origin 'https://mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

And that doesn't happen when I run the web API locally. Why is it that it only occurs after I publish the files to my host and use the actual domain?
(I tried making the same request from the client when it's running locally too but it gives the exact same exception)

*I switched out the domain name in the question to `mywebsite.com` because I don't want to share it.*

Here is my ConfigurationServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://mywebsite.com",
                                              "http://localhost:8080",
                                              "https://mywebsite.com/add")
                                              .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                                              .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });

    });
...
```

And the Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "mcraftserverapi v1"));
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                     .RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! :-)

Comment: I wouldn't use `.WithOrigins(...)` with `.AllowAnyOrigin()`. It doesn't make sense since you're saying "these origins are OK" and then "all origins are OK".

Comment: I'll try removing `.WithOrigins(...)`. I figured it would work the first time when I was using only that but it turns out that it didn't allow the origin even though I specified it.

Comment: see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#forwarded-headers-middleware-order

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network tool to check the response header, whether it contains the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" property or not? If it doesn't contain the property, you have to add it. Besides, if your App(s) are hosted on IIS, you can try to [install IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) and configure CORS for the app. Reference: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-cors).

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove

```
 builder.WithOrigins("https://mywebsite.com",
  "http://localhost:8080"
 )
```

or

```
.AllowAnyOrigin()
```

you can't use them together